# How would I complete my proof that $\int_a^bf(g(x))\,dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)\frac{d}{dx}(g^{-1}(x))\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Around two years ago during a second semester calculus class, my professor remarked that $\int\sin(x^2)\,dx$ could not be integrated. Being a bit defiant, I tried (in vain) to prove him wrong.  While my efforts (obviously) were not successful, I did notice that: $$\int_a^bf(g(x))\,dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)\frac{d}{dx}(g^{-1}(x))\,dx$$

Will hold if $g(x)$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on the interval from $a$ to $b$.

I worked this out via intuition initially, but I recently decided I would try to prove it formally.  What I have so far is below.

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that $g'(x) > 0$ for $a < x < b$.

Let $P_n = \{[x_0,x_1],[x_1,x_2],...,[x_{n-1},x_n]\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{i} - x_{i-1} = 0$ for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n (f(g(x_i)))(x_i-x_{i-1}) = \int_a^b f(g(x))\,dx$$

Let $S_n = \{[g(x_0),g(x_1)],[g(x_1),g(x_2)],...,[g(x_{n-1}),g(x_n)]\}$ be a partition of $[g(a),g(b)]$.

At this point I planned to show: $$(f(g(x_i))\frac{d}{dx}g^{-1}(g(x_i)))(g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1})) = (f(g(x_i)))(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ I have intuition that this would work, but I can't see how to actually do it. I feel like I am missing something obvious, I just can't tell what that is.

With that result I planned to finish the proof by showing that \begin{align}\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)\frac{d}{dx}(g^{-1}(x))\,dx =& \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n (f(g(x_i))\frac{d}{dx}g^{-1}(g(x_i)))(g(x_i)-g(x_{i-1}))\\
=& \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n (f(g(x_i)))(x_i-x_{i-1})\\
=&\int_a^bf(g(x))\,dx\end{align}

I have a pretty good idea of how I would do these last steps, it is just showing that one equality that is tripping me up.

So my question is *how would I complete this proof or modify it so that it can be completed easily?* Or *if the original assertion is flawed please provide a counterexample.* I know you could probably get this result through substitution, but I wanted to try to get it with Riemann sums for practice.

Comment: Just use integration by parts (substituting $t=g(x)$) and formula for derivative of inverse function

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28sin%28x%C2%B2%29%29%29dx%29

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I am aware that $\int\sin(x^2)\,dx$ can't be written in terms of elementary functions, I just like to test things like that for myself.  Thank you anyway though.

Comment: @ixsetf: Your presumed proof via the substitution rule _is_ a formal proof. :) (You probably want to assume "$g'$ is non-vanishing"; that's not implied by "$g$ is strictly monotone".) If instead you write out a proof using Riemann sums, you can use the chain rule and the mean value theorem to establish the step you ask about, but then you're effectively re-proving the one-line substitution proof (for $f$ the identity function) interval-by-interval.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for the comment and suggestions. You are right that a proof using the substitution rule is perfectly valid, and it would definitely have been faster. I just went to Riemann sums because it matched the logic of initial way I thought of the identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g(g^{-1}(x))=x => g(g^{-1}(x))'=g'(g^{-1}(x)) \cdot (g^{-1}(x))'=1 => (g^{-1}(x))'= \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(x))}$ and $(g^{-1}(g(x_{i})))'= \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(g(x_{i})))}=\frac{1}{g'(x_{i})}$. Also applying mean value theorem, a variance of it $g(x_{i})-g(x_{i-1})=g'(\mu_{i}) \cdot (x_{i}-x_{i-1})$, $\mu_{i} \in (x_{i-1}, x_{i})$. As a result:
$$f(g(x_{i})) \cdot (g^{-1}(g(x_{i})))' \cdot (g(x_{i})-g(x_{i-1}))=f(g(x_{i})) \cdot \frac{g'(\mu_{i})}{g'(x_{i})} \cdot (x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$

It should be easy to prove that $$\\lim_{\Delta x_{i}\rightarrow 0} \frac{g'(\mu_{i})}{g'(x_{i})}=1$$ where $\Delta x_{i}=x_{i}-x_{i-1}$